# Where are the different event status values documented?

Tags: eventbrite

In eventbrite, the [`event` object has many fields](https://www.eventbrite.com/developer/v3/response_formats/event/), one of which is "status" ...

- **status** string: One of *canceled*, *live*, *started*, *ended*, *completed*

But where are the meanings of those different status values documented? Particularly, how is *ended* different from *completed*? And why are some events marked as *live* even though they occurred last month?

Answer (score 1):

The status string is directly related to what state your event is in.

- Canceled: the event was canceled and is no longer taking place.
- Live: the event is on the Eventbrite platform and tickets are available for
  purchase.
- Started: The event has started.
- Ended: The event has ended.
- Complete: (This status is specific to the event organizer.) The payout has been sent from Eventbrite to the event organizer.

I am not sure about the last question... I'm guessing it has to do with series/repeating events.

Comment: Thanks. That would appear to make sense but there are events from a month ago lingering with _live_ and _ended_ status. Is "the state the event is in" determined automatically per the event date-time, or is it triggered by manual intervention?

Comment: Do you have an example event this has happened on?